# Index numpy array by matrix of two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array like

```
weights = np.array(
    [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9],
    ]
)
```

And i have two 1-D numpy arrays that i want to use to index into weights

```
positions1 = np.array([2, 1, 0])
positions2 = np.array([1, 1, 0])
```

If i want the results for stepping through the arrays together and indexing into the matrix that way i can do

```
print(weights[positions1[...], positions2[...]])
```

And get `[8 5 1]`

However now i want to index into the matrix with all possible combinations of positions1 and positions2 so that i get a matrix like

```
[
[weights[2, 1], weights[2, 1], weights[2, 0]],
[weights[1, 1], weights[1, 1], weights[1, 0]],
[weights[0, 1], weights[0, 1], weights[0, 0]],
]
```

So

```
[
[weights[pos1[0], pos2[0]], weights[pos1[0], pos2[1]], weights[pos1[0], pos2[2]]],
[weights[pos1[1], pos2[0]], weights[pos1[1], pos2[1]], weights[pos1[1], pos2[2]]],
[weights[pos1[2], pos2[0]], weights[pos1[2], pos2[1]], weights[pos1[2], pos2[2]]],
]
```

What would be the canonical way to do that in numpy?
I know that this is kinda like an outer product but i dont actually want to multiply the values in my array but just get a tuple of their values to index into the matrix with.

Comment: Have a look at the second example under the [integer array indexing docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). The canonical numpy way is to use [`np.ix_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change the shape of the first indexer:

```
weights[positions1[:,None], positions2]
```

Or for a generalized version, as pointed out by Chrysophylaxs:

```
weights[np.ix_[positions1, positions2]]
```

Output:

```
array([[8, 8, 7],
       [5, 5, 4],
       [2, 2, 1]])
```

Comment: Nice, that is exactly what i needed.

I have a similar problem at another point but there i also know that my result matrix is symmetric. Is there a way to only do this for one half of the 2D array?

Comment: @J.N. you can maybe use `np.triu`/`np.tril`?

Comment: If i understood the docs correctly they just zero the matrix after the fact. I would like to try to not calculate them in the first place to save time and space.

Comment: Then I don't see a vectorial way. With `itertools.combinations` you can get the combinations of coordinates (i.e. no duplicates)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Then ill just do the whole thing. Im pretty sure that vectorizing this gives me a more than 2x speed boost and so it would still be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
weights[*np.meshgrid(positions1, positions2, indexing='ij')]
```

If the above does not work on your Python version, you can use what @mozway suggests:

```
weights[tuple(np.meshgrid(positions1, positions2, indexing='ij'))]
```

Output:

```
array([[8, 8, 7],
       [5, 5, 4],
       [2, 2, 1]])
```

Comment: That might not work on all python versions (<3.11), maybe `weights[tuple(np.meshgrid(positions1, positions2, indexing='ij'))]`

Comment: Thanks, @mozway, for letting me know that! I have just updated my answer accordingly.